# Mongoid configuration - sessions vs clients

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, mongoid, config

I am new to Rails and I inherited a project that uses MongoDb. The adapter is Mongoid.

We have two applications - Site and API. The Site and the API utilize the same mongo server and database.

But the **Site** configuration is slightly different from the **API** configuration:

**Site** *mongiid.yml*:

```
production:
  clients:
    default:
      hosts:
      - mongodb-db2:27017
      database: db
      username: user_blah
      password: pass_blah
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

**API** *mongoid.yml*

```
production:
  sessions:
    default:
      hosts:
      - mongodb-db2:27017
      database: db
      username: user_blah
      password: pass_blah
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

Please note the difference `sessions` cs `clients`.

I searched in the Internet to find what is the difference and came across to this https://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid%2FConfig:clients , 
but didn't find what is the difference (**if any**)

The question is: Is there a difference between these two configurations? I yes - some link with explanation or reference? I do not dare to make these files identical.

**============ EDIT ============**

Mongoid gem versions:

API: `mongoid (4.0.2)`

Site: `mongo (2.6.2)
mongoid (7.0.1)`

Comment: What about Mongoid versions for both projects?

Comment: Please see the edit section of my post

Answer (score 0):

Mongoid 4 and 7 are significantly different. They also have different configuration.

Mongoid 4 documentation: http://mongoid.github.io/old/en/mongoid/index.html

Mongoid 7 documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/7.0/

Mongoid 4 is no longer supported, and projects using it should upgrade to Mongoid 7.